# Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var alphNames = ["ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQR","STU"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberofRowInsection section: Int) -> Int {
        return alphNames.count 
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath : indexPath) as UITableViewCell

           //Configure the cell...
           cell.textLabel?.text = departmentNames[indexPath.row]
           return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: You **should describe* your program, what is it supposed to do and what is your problem (error, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made an typo in `numberOfRowsInSection` function. It is a **required** function of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. It should be

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return alphNames.count
}
```

You have typed `numberofRowInsection` instead.

Comment: var alphNames = ["ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQR","STU"]
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInsection section: Int) ->
    Int
    {return alphNames.count }

Comment: still appears Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Comment: please check the exact case of the letters i have used in the function. you typed `numberOfRowsInsection` it is actually `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: it do works.. thank you ,I apologize for my careless

Comment: Thanks, It hepled me

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement all the required functions. You can see them by command clicking on the UITableViewDataSource. To make sure you don't make any typo, just copy the required functions or start typing in the ViewController the name of the function and autocompletion should do the rest.