# 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have searched and got these questions, addressing the same problem.

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581780/type-viewcontroller-does-not-conform-to-protocol-uitableviewdatasource)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935848/ios-myviewcontroller-does-not-conform-to-protocol-uitableviewdatasource)
- [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322531/type-viewcontroller-does-not-conform-to-protocol-uitableviewdatasource)

But, I am not making any mistakes mentioned in answers to these.

Here is my code:

```
class RightViewController: ParentViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

//properties
var itemsArray: [String] = ["set", "git"]
@IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView! = UITableView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //register cell

    self.tableView!.registerClass(MenuCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell")
    tableView!.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView!.estimatedRowHeight = 140
    tableView!.delegate = self
    tableView!.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: <TableViewDataSource>

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuCell

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row < itemsArray.count {
        let option = itemsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        cell.titleLabel?.text = option

    }

    return cell

}
```

I have implemented all the required protocol methods, they are inside my class's scope. And still I get this annoying error. `ParentViewController` in my code is actually another `UIViewController`

[image]
Where I might be wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should follow delegate methods signature. cellForRowAt replace with cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using lower version of `swift` not `swift 3.0`, method `cellForRowAt indexPath` is work with swift 3.0, so you need to use this `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of that.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuCell        
    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row < itemsArray.count {
        let option = itemsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]            
        cell.titleLabel?.text = option            
    }        
    return cell        
}
```